# Asp.net How can i get the transaction history of paypal account on my website using paypal email id and password

Tags: asp.net

Asp.net How can i get the transaction history of paypal account on my website using paypal email id and password.As I want to Import the Paypal transaction logs in my website for financial management on my site...

Comment: I really want to know how this has do be done, too!
Im sure, its possible, because a software called StarMoney is doing it. It asks for paypal username and password and can query all transactions from my account without require me to grant some API user some rights.

Today i'm only aware of the SearchTransactions API call where you can specify another account via the SUBJECT parameter. But the foreign account has to grant access to your API key beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You will only be able to do this if PayPal expose an API where you can obtain the information from - which I don't think they do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, StarMoney is doing screenscraping...

The answer to your question is: Its not possible to query another account just by submitting email and password to an API call.

But: You can use the [TransactionSearch](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_TransactionSearch) API call with the SUBJECT Parameter to specify the Pay Pal account you want to query.
For this to work, the other Pay Pal user has to grant access to your API registration beforehand.